# Get datatable current draw query string to send to server for export as report

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a datatable drawing data from the server. i tried tabletools to export pdf and excel but it only exported what was on the first page of the datatable, it did not export including the other pages on the datatable pagination.

Therefore i want to the get the query string for the current draw so that i can add it to a link that points to another server request url which would generate report from there.

here is my datatable script:

```
table = $('#table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,            
        ajax: {
        url: "http://xxxx/sales",
        data: function ( d ) {
            d.dateGroup = $(".btn.active").attr("data-ecvalue");
            d.startDate = $("input[name=daterangepicker_start]").val();
            d.endDate = $("input[name=daterangepicker_end]").val();               
        }},
        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "tableTools": {
            "aButtons": [
                {
                    "sExtends": "copy",
                    "sButtonText": "Copy to clipboard"
                },
                {
                    "sExtends": "csv",
                    "sButtonText": "Save to CSV"
                },
                {
                    "sExtends": "xls",
                    "oSelectorOpts": {
                        page: 'current'
                    }
                },
                 {
                      "sExtends": "download",
                      "sButtonText": "Download PDF",
                      "sUrl":     "exportpdf"
                 }
            ]
        },
        type:"POST",
        columns: [
        { "data": "date" },
        { "data": "order" },
        { "data": "totals" },
        { "data": "subtotals" }
        ]
});
```

I tried : `var mydata = table.fnSettings();
 alert(mydata );`

but dont know how to do that.....

Am using datatables v1.10.

Comment: The next code gave me the object for the data sent to server, BUT i wanted the URL itself: Can i convert the object from this code to a url request to server ? table.on( 'xhr', function () {
      var data = table.ajax.params();
      var x = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
      alert(x);
    } );

Answer (score 5):

You're almost there with your code.

I was trying to do exactly what you explained. So, I managed this way:

```
$('#export-csv').on('click', function(){
    var data = table.ajax.params(); 
    var x = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4); 

    $(this).attr("href", this.href + "?" + $.param(data) + '&o=csv');
})
```